# Mission Planner src build issue

Tags: mission-planner

I am building src of mission planner in Visual Studio 2022.
But I am facing these issues.can anyone help me to resolve these issues?

Error #1:

> SF\Downloads\MissionPlanner-master\MissionPlanner-master\bin\Debug\net461' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> 50> operable program or batch file.

Error #2:

> Error NU1104
> Unable to find project 'C:\Users\CR&SF\Documents\src\MissionPlanner\ExtLibs\mono\mcs\class\System.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms-net_4_x.csproj'. Check that the project reference is valid and that the project file exists.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issues.
Error # 1 solution:

there should not be & or space between path where you have saved mission planner src. in my case path was 'C:\Users\CR&SF\Documents\src\MissionPlanner. so here it is & symbol. i changed the directory for saving src and it rsolved the error.

Error # 2 Solution:

open git bash and write
1.git init
2. git submodule update --recursive
it will resolve Nu1104 error